# How to bring back the old options windows in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox

The most recent Firefox beta build has removed the old options windows.
Now when I click on options, I get this:

[image: http://i21.servimg.com/u/f21/13/13/40/49/untitl10.jpg]

The preference **browser.preferences.inContent** has also been removed. It was previously a boolean which would keep the old options window if set to false.

Is there any way to bring back the old options window, or is it gone for good now? :(

I'm using Firefox 42.0b3 on Windows 7 home premium 64bit.

Comment: I don't know a way. This new way is much better. The old way blocked Firefox completely until you closed the options.

Answer (score 1):

Have to use an extension now, this is the only one I have seen so far.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/options-dialog-restorer/